# Search through documents folder

Tags: php, search, pdf

Does anyone know why the following returns nothing?

```
<?php 
    $dir = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/documents/*";
    foreach(glob($dir) as $file) {
        echo $file;  
    }
?>
```

I have files in the documents folder...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_bloginfo('template_directory')` returns a URI and I believe `glob` works with paths so try:

```
$dir =  get_theme_root() . "/documents/*";
foreach(glob($dir) as $file) {
    echo $file;  
}
```